# Anything similar to Maya for making animation-movies under Ubuntu?

Tags: video, presentation

Are there any programs similar to [Maya, for making animation-movies](http://www.autodesk.com/products/autodesk-maya/overview) under Ubuntu?  I.e. programs where you make keyframes, and the program fill in the inbetweens.

I want to make a short video for plugging a web-site, with some drawings moving around.  To be frank, I planning to make a presentation more similar to PowerPoint; but with more movement (animation) of the graphics and figures (more like a cartoon) than you can get with normal presentation-programs.  I guess I may have tried Flash under Windows (if I had it), though I would prefer something a bit more advanced (help a bit more with the animation)...

Any suggestions for a good application to do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a very powerful 3D modelling and animation package called [Blender](http://www.blender.org/).  You can get the latest version from the link.

Blender is an integrated 3d suite for modelling, animation, rendering,
post-production, interactive creation and playback (games). Blender has its
own particular user interface, which is implemented entirely in OpenGL and
designed with speed in mind. Python bindings are available for scripting;
import/export features for popular file formats like 3D Studio and Wavefront
Obj are implemented as scripts by the community. Stills, animations, models
for games or other third party engines and interactive content in the form of
a standalone binary are common products of Blender use.

Alternatively you can find a earlier version in the software centre.